# Spring Data Cassandra Naming Strategy

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

Kotlin + Spring Boot Cassandra App is ignoring `@Column("column_name")` annotations. The below annotation

```
@Column("order_details")
val orderDetails: String
```

Is being mapped to `orderdetails` instead of `order_details`. As the column `orderdetails` doesn't exist in the table, it causes a run time error.

Why doesn't spring data Cassandra's `@Column` map to snake case by default?
Even after the value is being passed to `@Column` mapping, why is it being ignored?
Is there any other property that needs to be set in the app properties so that spring data Cassandra uses snake case for physical mapping?

```
@Table("order_by_customer")
data class CustomerOrder(
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "customer_id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    val customerId: UUID,
    @Column("order_details")
    val orderDetails: String,
    @Column("ordered_at")
    val orderedAt: LocalDate
)
```

Generated insert query
`INSERT INTO order_by_customer (customer_id,orderdetails,orderedat)`

While annotation for PK work the ones for Column are being ignored

Answer (score 3):

Per the resolution provided by spring-data-cassandra team. Data class need to be coded as shown below

```kotlin
    @Table("order_by_customer")
    data class CustomerOrder(
        @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "customer_id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
        val customerId: UUID,
        @field:Column("order_details")
        val orderDetails: String,
        @field:Column("ordered_at")
        val orderedAt: LocalDate
    )
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/issues/1146

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets